# Graph is not in ascending order

Tags: r, ggplot2

The graph we created should show the y column in ascending order, but it changes the scale or the order maybe??

[image: Graph in question]

```
dev.new()
library(ggplot2)
tabela <- read.table("C:/Users/pedro/OneDrive/Ambiente de Trabalho/hicp.csv", sep = ';', header = T)
tabela_bread_c = tabela[c(5, 34, 63, 92, 121, 150, 179, 208, 237, 266, 295, 324, 353), 3]
head(tabela_bread_c, n=13L)
tabela_poultry = tabela[c(18, 47, 76, 105, 134, 163, 192, 221, 250, 279, 308, 337, 366), 3]
head(tabela_poultry, n=13L)

anos = tabela[c(5, 34, 63, 92, 121, 150, 179, 208, 237, 266, 295, 324, 353), 1]
head(anos, n=13L)
dados_totais = cbind(anos, tabela_bread_c)
colnames(dados_totais) <- c("Ano", "valor")

dados_totais <- strtoi(dados_totais, base=16)
df <- data.frame(x=anos, y=tabela_bread_c)
head(df, n=13L)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(title="Evolução de preços") + ylab("Preço dos Produtos") + xlab("Ano e Mês")
```

We don't really know how to fix this

Comment: From the image I would guess that your `y` column is a character instead of a numeric, especially as the values have a `,` as the decimal mark. Try with converting to a numeric before plotting using e.g. `df$y <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", df$y))`

Comment: Thank you so much! it's working as intended now